# ActiveRecord scope based on hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

**iteration**

```
<% @challenges.with_exact.each do |challenge| %>
 etc...
<% end %>
```

**model scope attempts**

```
scope :with_exact, -> { where("exact == ?", Time.zone.now.hour) } # Error: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: time without time zone == integer
scope :with_exact, -> { where(exact: Time.zone.now.hour) } # Error: PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "13"
```

Some challenges will have a `nil` exact.

How can I iterate challenges only where `Time.zone.now.strftime('%H') == challenge.exact.strftime('%H')`

Comment: *exact* is of type `datetime` or `time`?

Comment: @Pavan looks like it is, `challenge.exact.strftime('%H')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`date_part(text, timestamp)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) postgres function:

```
where("date_part('hour', exact) = ?", Time.zone.now.hour)
```

Here is also `month`, `year` and so on.

There is an another way with [`extract(field from timestamp)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
where("extract(hour from exact) = ?", Time.zone.now.hour)
```